# Errors appearing in terminal after updating Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, ubuntu-17.04

I ran `conda update --all` recently and now every time I open a new terminal I get these error lines at the top:

```
ERROR: This cross-compiler package contains no program /bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-addr2line
ERROR: activate-binutils_linux-64.sh failed, see above for details
ERROR: This cross-compiler package contains no program /bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc
ERROR: activate-gcc_linux-64.sh failed, see above for details
ERROR: This cross-compiler package contains no program /bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++
ERROR: activate-gxx_linux-64.sh failed, see above for details
(anaconda3-4.4.0) imran@holly:~$
```

Any idea what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: What packages do you have installed? Do you have any of the compiler packages installed? What version of conda do you have?

Comment: I am running anaconda3-4.4.0 and I have gcc_impl_linux-64 and gcc_linux-64 installed. Do you want a full list of packages?

Comment: What happens if you uninstall those compiler packages?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `conda --version`

Comment: `conda --version` gives `conda 4.3.30`. I removed gcc_linux-64, gcc_impl_linux-64, binutils_linux-64, and binutils_impl_linux-64 and the errors were gone. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure! I'm not sure what effect that will have on your environment, so you may want to re-install them. It's possible that conda doesn't handle files existing files being removed very well, but if you re-install it will be fine. YMMV

Comment: I used `conda remove` which also removes all packages depending on these, and I didn't see anything I wanted to keep so it should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this with:

```
conda remove gcc_linux-64 gcc_impl_linux-64 binutils_linux-64 binutils_impl_linux-64
```

Thanks to the help in the comments from @darthbith